# Call FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage 10'000 times?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Is it OK to call  `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` many times?

On login page we test if user is already logged in, and if it is we just redirect him to default page with `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`...

Question is if user sets a script that loads login page 10'000 times, would calling the  `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` that many times make problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On login page we test if user is
>   already logged in, and if it is we
>   just redirect him to default page with
>   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage...

The times when user goes to login page when already logged-in is

(i) either they go to that page manaually(i.e. they enter the url to your login page)

(ii) or is sent their by some manual redirect in your code or

(iii)if he/she is unauthorized to view some resource and redirect by asp.net authorization module.

Depending how user reaches the login page you might want to take appropriate action. In any above cases I would not use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage. The only time I would use it on login page is when user clicks login button and credentials are valid.

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage will create a new authentication ticket everytime it is called. I would just do hard redirect for the scenarion you have described:

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated){
Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
}
```

You should consider the 3 points I mentioned above before using the code.